How can I retrieve (or replace) one LUKS password, given a second one
The good news is that I can unlock my LUKS encrypted home partition.  Keyslot 1 ties to a file on a USB stick that my /etc/crypttab uses to automatically unlock.  And so as long as a cheap USB stick never ever dies or suffers a tragedy, I'm fine.
The bad news is I think I've lost track of whatever manual unlock key is supposed to unlock keyslot 0.  So if I ever need that bailout I'm in a bad way.
What can I do now to be able to manually unlock this LUKS partition in the future when the entirely predictable comes my way?  Can I retrieve key 0 given that key 1 works?  Can I set a new key 2 with what information I currently have?
